# Scrapy make_requests_from_url(url)

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

In the Scrapy tutorial there is this method of the BaseSpider:

> [make_requests_from_url(url)](http://doc.scrapy.org/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spider.BaseSpider.make_requests_from_url)
>
> A method that receives a URL and
> returns a Request object (or a list of
> Request objects) to scrape.
>
> This method is used to construct the
> initial requests in the
> start_requests() method, and is
> typically used to convert urls to
> requests.
>
> Unless overridden, this method returns
> Requests with the parse() method as
> their callback function, and with
> dont_filter parameter enabled (see
> Request class for more info).

Do you understand what this method does? And can I use makerequestsfrom_url and BaseSpider instead of SgmlLinkExtractor and CrawlSpider that is not working for me?

I am trying to crawl more than the given initial url and Scrapy is not doing that.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

That's right, the [CrawlSpider](http://doc.scrapy.org/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider) is useful and convenient in many cases, but it only covers a subset of all possible spiders. If you need something more complex, you typically subclass [BaseSpider](http://doc.scrapy.org/topics/spiders.html#basespider) and implement [start_requests()](http://doc.scrapy.org/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spider.BaseSpider.start_requests) method.